# How to set toast in ViewPage

Tags: android, android-toast

I am trying to set toast in my PagerAdapter class but it is showing error as not aencloser class .what should I change in my code.But I am gettin error as
com.example.neelaysrivastava.batmanvsupermanwallpaper.MainActivity is not a enclosing class"

```
 package com.example.neelaysrivastava.batmanvsupermanwallpaper;

 import android.app.WallpaperManager;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.res.Resources;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
  import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.IOException;


 class CustomeSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context ctx;
private int[] imgID ={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6,
        R.drawable.img7,R.drawable.img8,R.drawable.img9,R.drawable.img10,R.drawable.img11,R.drawable.img12,R.drawable.img13,
        R.drawable.img14,R.drawable.img15,R.drawable.img16,R.drawable.img17,R.drawable.img18,R.drawable.img19,
        R.drawable.img20,R.drawable.img21,R.drawable.img22,R.drawable.img23,R.drawable.img24,R.drawable.img25,R.drawable.img26,
        R.drawable.img27,R.drawable.img28,R.drawable.img29,R.drawable.img30,R.drawable.img31,R.drawable.img32,R.drawable.img33,
        R.drawable.img34,R.drawable.img35,R.drawable.img36,R.drawable.img37,R.drawable.img38
};
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public CustomeSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx=ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imgID.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
}
Bitmap goal;
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.extra,container,false);
    ImageView imageView =(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Button button=(Button)item_view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgID[position]);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx.getBaseContext(), "wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), imgID[position]);
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager =
                    WallpaperManager.getInstance(ctx.getApplicationContext());
            try {
                int height = wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
                int width = wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
                Bitmap bm =
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(v.getContext().getResources(), imgID[position]);
                goal = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, true);
                v.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imgID[position]);
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(goal);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

}

Comment: As a first step you could tell us exactly what the error is.

Comment: Instead of using `ctx.getBaseContext()` in your onClickListener you could just use `v.getContext()` since the context of v should be that of the hosting Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Though you have not supplied enough code but as per experience I think The reasons could be

1. either you have not mentioned the so called activity in the manifest file

2.you are not giving context to the respective toast try to pass the context if its a subclass

---

3. or maybe you could change the line

   `Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

to

```
    `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "wallpaper set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
```